# Custom GraphQL Directive Logic Implemention

Tags: go, graphql, directive

I have a rapidly growing GraphQL schema written in `go` using the `github.com/graphql-go/graphql` library and am trying to implement a custom directive for field definitions for authentication.

I'm instantiating the directive object with:

```golang
var AuthenticatedDirective = graphql.NewDirective(graphql.DirectiveConfig{
    Name:        "authenticated",
    Description: "Identifies a query or mutation as requiring authentication for resolution",
    Locations:   []string{graphql.DirectiveLocationFieldDefinition},
    Args: graphql.FieldConfigArgument{
        "type": &graphql.ArgumentConfig{
            Type: graphql.NewNonNull(graphql.String),
        },
    },
})
```

...appending it to the schema by:

```golang
var customDirectives = []*graphql.Directive{
    types.AuthenticatedDirective,
}

func CompileSchema(query *graphql.Object, mutation *graphql.Object) (graphql.Schema, error) {
    return graphql.NewSchema(graphql.SchemaConfig{
        Query:      query,
        Mutation:   mutation,
        Directives: append(graphql.SpecifiedDirectives, customDirectives...),
    })
}
```

These two combined appropriately creates and injects the directive definition into the schema so that it's available to use, however, there doesn't seem to be a clear way to implement the logic behind processing the directive or assigning it to field definitions.

For instance, if I have a `Query` field definition like:

```golang
// type Query {
//   me: @authenticated(type: "jwt")
// }
"me": &graphql.Field{
    Description: "(Authenticated) Parses and validates the authorization header token and returns the targeted User",
    Type:        types.UserType,
    Resolve:     resolvers.MeResolver,
},
```

How do I go about assigning the directive to this query field definition and implementing the JWT validation logic via visiting the directive?

Comment: Directives are an SDL (schema definition language) feature. You could probably define custom query directives that could be utilized by a client when writing a query. Defining schema directives, though, is a bit useless in this context because you're not using SDL to create your schema. If you need a way to apply common logic to multiple resolvers, you should be able to just use a [higher order function](https://www.golangprograms.com/higher-order-functions-in-golang.html).

Comment: @DanielRearden yeah i've implemented it perfectly fine for the time being using HOFs and contexts but there seems to be a gap in functionality here...the library allows us to define custom directive objects but not implement the processing logic behind them, rendering them useless

Comment: The reference implementation, which the golang one is based on, is the same way.